# Reading from a plain text file

Tags: python

Say I have the following in a text file:

> car
>   apple
>   bike
>   book

How can I read it and put them into a dictionary or a list?

Comment: It's in the manual: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Just to spell out what is obvious to most people (but not everyone, which is evident from some of the duplicates of this question): Python doesn't care what the name of the file is, or, in particular, whether it has an extension and if that extension is `.txt`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading them into a list is trivially done with [`readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```
f = open('your-file.dat')
yourList = f.readlines()
```

If you need the newlines stripped out you can use [ars' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287179/reading-from-a-plain-text-file/3287211#3287211), or do:

```
yourList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

If you want a dictionary with keys from 1 to the length of the list, the first way that comes to mind is to make the list as above and then do:

```
yourDict = dict(zip(xrange(1, len(yourList)+1), yourList))
```

Comment: It's a good habit to use `with open('your-file.dat') as f:` so that the file handle is closed properly.

Comment: @blokeley It is, but depending on version that can involve importing from `__future__`, and I'm not going to bother explaining all that for a two-line code snippet

Answer (score 3):

You can use the file with [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343) like this. This is called a context manager and automatically closes the file at the end of the indented block

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()
```

If you want to do it without a context manager, you should close the file yourself

```
f = open('data.txt')
words = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Otherwise the file remains open at least as long as `f` is still in scope

Answer (score 2):

```
words = []
for word in open('words.txt'):
    words.append(word.rstrip('\n'))
```

The `words` list will contain the words in your file.  `strip` removes the newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered pretty thoroughly in [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```
lines = open('filename.txt', 'r').readlines()
```