# Value Error when unpickling a file

Tags: python, file, pickle

I have been given a file that contains two pickled objects- it was sent to me as a .pk file. I was told it had two objects, however, my attempt to unpikle these files is unsuccessful.

The first pickled object contains a dictionary of pairs of numbers with their roman numerals, and the second contains dictionary pairs of roman numerals with their numbers. How can I unpickle these two dictionaries separately?

This is what I have below, along with the error message I am receiving:

```
import pickle
x,y=pickle.load(open("C://Users//Documents//roman.pk", "rb"))
print(x,y)
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What happens if you just `pickle.load` to a single object, then look at what it contains? One of the dictionaries? Something else? You could also try calling `pickle.load` twice on the same file (i.e. `open` it once, then `load` from it twice). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20716812/3001761

Comment: If I run it with just one variable, then it gives me one of the dictionaries. If I try to load from it twice it just gives me the first dictionary twice.

Comment: Are you using `load(open(...))` both times? If so, that will reset the pointer to the start of the file. You need to **open it once** (using the `with` context manager, ideally - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3287367/3001761).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your answer. Switched the format as you suggested and it is working! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pickle.load` will only load the first pickled object that it finds in the file. In your case, that's a dictionary with more than two keys, so `x, y = pickle.load(...)` fails because it's trying to unpack *the dictionary's keys* to the identifiers `x` and `y`.

Instead, you should `open` the file once, and `load` from it twice:

```
with open("...roman.pk") as file_:
    first_dict = pickle.load(file_)  # file pointer is now at end of first object
    second_dict = pickle.load(file_)  # read in second object
```

Alternatively, encourage whoever is supplying you with the file to put the two dictionaries into a single object, e.g. a tuple `(first_dict, second_dict)` and `pickle` that single object; this is much easier than relying on knowing exactly how many pickled objects are in the file.

Answer (score -1):

pickle.load should load the data structure into one parameter.
if you have 2 dictionary in roman.pk, it depends on how the 2 dictionary are grouped

e.g (dict1, dict2)

In this case:
You probably want to try:
(x,y)= pickle.load(open("C://Users//Documents//roman.pk", "rb"))
print len(x)
print len(y) 
To check if it loads correctly

Comment: `(x, y) = ...` is exactly the same as `x, y = ...` and will fail for the same reason