# Python 2 - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)

Tags: python, save, load

I keep getting this error and i dont know how to fix it i need help.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
```

This is how i load

```
with open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f:
    money, hunger, thirst, energy, wanted, gun = pickle.load(f)
```

and this is how i save

```
with open('objs.pickle', 'ab') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'wb')
    pickle.dump([money, hunger, thirst, energy, gun, wanted], f)
```

Comment: You've opened the file in `ab` mode when serializing the data. Why? And why would you open it in a different mode on Python 3? It sounds like you might have other junk in this file.

Comment: Check what `pickle.load(f)` returns. It must be a single element.

Comment: its returns the money variable

Comment: This problem has been addressed earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29559840/4399016

Comment: thanks i think its fixed now

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pickle.load will only load the first pickled object that it finds in the file. In your case, that's a dictionary with more than two keys, so x, y = pickle.load(...) fails because it's trying to unpack the dictionary's keys to the identifiers x and y.

```
with open("objs.pickle") as f:
    first_dict = pickle.load(f)  # file pointer is now at end of first object
    second_dict = pickle.load(f)  # read in second object
```

Etc.

You are better off if you put these words into a single object, e.g. a tuple  and pickle that single object. This is much easier when you don not know exactly how many pickled objects are in the file.

```
my_list = ['money', 'hunger', 'thirst', 'energy', 'wanted', 'gun']
tuple(my_list)
```

Now it is easier to pickle the tuple my_list.

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'